# How do I implement webapi security if the client is an application

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around Webapi security. I can set up the Webapi no problem. But the client is the problem. The client is an application not a user. And the client makes java script calls. So is there a single account for the application? And how do I store a username/password for the application to use in an Ajax call? There is no 'logging in'. It's an application.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of client you are talking about. Is it a SPA (Single Page Application)? Or another application (server-side) hosted somewhere else? Is the client used by a user or it is some kind of external service?

Comment: The client is a sitecore website. So a user of the sitecore website, who is not logged in performs a task that calls the WebAPI and gets some data in response that can be displayed on the sitecore site. The call to the WebAPI will be from Javascript.

Comment: If requests will be made from JavaScript, and the user can be anonymous, then you have no way to protect your API, because even if you restrict access to credentials known only by the client, those credentials are exposed to the public since your client is in JavaScript. I suggest you to simply allow access to your endpoints publicly OR do requests to Web API server-side (inside sitecore). In the latter you can protect your API easily using [OAuth Client Credentials Grant](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) type.

Comment: What about OAuth implicit flow?

Comment: Implicit flow (like resource owner credentials and authorization code) requires a user to authenticate himself. It's not an option if you allow use of your API from anonymous users.